# Num Lock key does nothing in Qt Application on QNX

Tags: qnx

I wrote a C++ GUI application using Qt 5.3 for QNX 6.5, but it doesn't let me enter any number from the numeric keypad to a QLineEdit widget even when the num lock is on. The num lock works fine on the console terminal. I built the application for Windows, and the num lock worked fine, too.